#  commenting in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

Ok..so here's the problem..i want to have facebook commenting on my productsDescription page..there are many products so when we click on a particular product it redirects to the productDescription page with the itemID in query string..now what i want is all the products have there own specific comment box.Now when i use the below code , with different itemID in query string the same comment box opens.

For Eg: If a user comments on a mobile(www.tc.com/gyjd.aspx?itemID=55) , and then navigates to view a laptop(www.tc.com/gyjd.aspx?itemID=77) he sees the comments he gave for the mobile. But what i want is with different itemID in query string the comment box should be new.Hope am not confusing.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="tc.com/gyjd.aspx" data-num-posts="5" data-width="500"></div>
```

Comment: when you save comment in database, did you store itemid like storing userid? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved that by doing a div called fbBtns.

Then I set it's innerHtml property on page behind:
fbBtns.InnerHtml = "";

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the proper querystring to the `data-href` attribute:

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="tc.com/gyjd.aspx?itemID=<%=Request.QueryString["itemID"]%>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="500"></div>
```

For VB.NET:

```html
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="tc.com/gyjd.aspx?itemID=<%=Request.QueryString("itemID")%>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="500"></div>
```

Comment: The url needs to be different, changing just the querystring will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have unique urls for the page (Facebook ignores the query string).  You could tell Facebook to use fake urls by setting the data-href to be something like "tc.com/qyjd/4" etc.  With .net 4, you can easily set up [page routes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).
 to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info..but i want it exactly like this [http://esparsha.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=youmania_flypage.tpl&product_id=49&category_id=8&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=151](http://esparsha.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=youmania_flypage.tpl&product_id=49&category_id=8&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=151)

Comment: Then specify a fake url without a querystring in the data-href and it will work.